# If $\lim t_n=0$, when does $\lim s_nt_n \neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a real-valued sequence $s_n$ such that $\lim s_nt_n \neq 0$,  given that $\lim t_n=0$. Any hints?

Comment: Choose $t_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $s_n=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many such examples, one of them is $s_n = n, t_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$